Blur Child Input Component from Parent in Svelte 5
I have a custom <MyInput /> component like this:
<script lang="ts">
//=== MyInput.svelte ===

type Props = {
  input: HTMLInputElement
  value: string
}

let { input = $bindable(), value = $bindable() }: Props = $props()
</script>

<input bind:this={input} bind:value />

I want to be able to programmatically blur this field from a parent component wherever it is used.
<script lang="ts">
//=== Parent.svelte ===
import MyInput from '$lib/MyInput.svelte'

let input: HTMLInputElement

function blurField(){
  input.blur() <!-- console error
}
</script>

<MyInput {input} {value} />
<button onclick={() => blurField()}>Blur Field</button>

I'm unclear on how to bind my reference to the input in the parent to the actual child component. It doesn't appear to actually have connected the input in the parent to the binding of the child.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

You have to bind: the component's input at the very least:
<MyInput bind:input {value} />

(Without it, values would only be passed down.)

So anytime I use $bindable() as a prop in a component, the parent referencing it needs to have bind: in order to connect to that bindable prop?

If you need the child to parent direction, yes. Likewise you also don't need $bindable if you don't intend to bind from the parent.

This has been very helpful. Thank you!
